# Electric field inside spherical capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

As per my knowledge, the electric field inside a metallic spherical shell is always zero. But while studying spherical-shell capacitors, I got confused: How can the electric field exist inside it if the electric field inside it has to be zero. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Because your capacitor has charge displaced inside the sphere, generating a field.

Comment: An important part of the concept is missing: the electric field inside a *statically-charged conductor* is always zero. If you have concentric shells, each with charge, that's a different situation because you have charge in the space inside the outer conductor, not actually on the outer conductor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a potential difference exists between the two by transferring charge from one to another electric field will be present in the gap between them only.

Comment: All this comes by applying Gauss law.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are right that electric field inside a conductor is zero instead it is zero for spherical capacitor if it would just consist of outer sphere only but as it consist of a small sphere to it creates some net electric field inside the big sphere making the field non zero.

Comment: Please, edit for make it clear. Without commas it's hard to understand.